# Example of a countably infinite subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ where the lower limit topology and the subspace topology are different

Tags: general-topology

I'm working on a homework problem:

Define a countably infinite subset $A \subset R$ so that the subspace topology on $A$ induced from the standard topology  $T_s$ on $R$ and the [lower limit topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) $T_l$ on $R$ will be different.

To solve this problem, I'm thinking like this: we know that the left-closed, right-open intervals $[a,b)$ are not open in the subspace topology $T_s$ but by definition, they're open in $T_l.$  I think this should be act as a hint, but now I need to construct a countably infinite subset $A$ of $R$ so that the restricted topology $T_s(A), T_l(A)$ are different.

**This is where I wanted to check if my solution is correct:** I tried the subset $A:=\{0\} \cup \{\pm 1/n: n \ge 1\}.$  Then any left-closed, right-open neighborhood  $U$ of $0$ in $A$ of the form $U:=A \cap [0,b), b <1$ is open in the subspace lower limit topology $T_l(A),$ but not open in the standard subspace topology $T_s(A)$ on $A,$ because in $T_s(A),$ any subset containing $0$ mist contain infinitely many points around $0$ which are both less and greater than $0,$ but this is not the case for the above $U.$ So $U$ is open subset of $(A, T_l(A))$ but not of $(A, T_s(A)).$

Is this correct? If not, could you please elaborate a bit? Thank you!

Comment: This looks great! Indeed, I think the slightly smaller example $\{0\}\cup\{-1,-\frac12,-\frac13,\dots\}$ works as well.

Comment: Ah yes for the same reason, but yes thank you for that!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an injective convergent (in the standard reals) sequence from the left plus its limit, like $A=\{\frac{-1}{n}\mid n=1,2,3,\ldots\}\cup \{0\}$, is infinite discrete in the lower-limit topology and compact in the Euclidean topology, so quite different.